# an i-drop <object> tag seems to deviate from the parent div on Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I am working on AutoDesk's iDrop indicator in Internet explorer and the object file seems to deviate from the parent .

How can I fix it to enforce the object image to fit to  box.

Preview of the idrop image at top and it's parent at the bottom

[image: Preview]